# Have outlook 365; when viewing storage I see all my folders, but they are not listed on the left pane when viewing my mailbox on main page

Tags: files-folders, microsoft-outlook-365

I am trying to switch from MacMail to Outlook 365.  When I view the main mailbox on Outlook 365, I am missing a lot of folders (I have expanded all carrots and they are not there).  However.....When I go the General/Storage on Outlook 365 to see all of my email count, I see all of my missing folders.  Why are they not showing on my panel?  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try repairing Office?  That would be the first thing to try.

Comment: Are these all subfolders? Are there main folders missing?